# JavaScript: update array of object using objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, key-value

I have one object and one is an array of objects like :

```
let obj = {
    id:'1',
    v1: '4',
    v2: '2',
    v3: '3',
}


const arr= [{key:1, value: 'v1'},{key:2, value:'v2'}]
```

here in the array of objects, I want concat values like this using key and value of obj

```
arr= [{key:1, value: 'v1:4'},{key:2, value:'v2:2'}]
```

basically, I just want to update the text value like this using object and an array of object

**Note** -  every time I'm getting a new object so how can I achieve this in loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let obj = {
  id: "1",
  v1: "4",
  v2: "2",
  v3: "3",
};

const arr = [
  { key: 1, value: "v1" },
  { key: 2, value: "v2" },
];

const result = arr.map(({ key, value }) => ({ key, value: `${value}:${obj[value]}` }));
console.log(result)
```

This solution uses [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `key` and `value` and looks up the values in the object using `obj[value]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
let obj = {
    id: '1',
    v1: '4',
    v2: '2',
    v3: '3',
};

const arr= [{key:1, value: 'v1'},{key:2, value:'v2'}];

arr.forEach((arrayObj, index) => {
    arr[index].value = Object.keys(obj).includes(arrayObj.value) ?  `${arrayObj.value}:${obj[arrayObj.value]}` : arrayObj.value
});

console.log(arr);
```